# Remove duplicate in linq list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a list of an entity

```
ID  NAME    Age Comment
1   B   33  C1
2   B   33  c2
3   A   33  c3
```

but i just want

```
ID  NAME    Age Comment
1   B   33  C1
3   A   33  c3
```

not want duplicate for name and age combination .

Comment: use linq method .Distinct(IEqualityComparer<String>)

Comment: @Xaruth can you please give an example for the above scenario. It would be helpful .Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var results = source.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age })
                    .Select(g => g.First())
                    .ToList();
```

Or you can use `DistinctBy` from [moreLINQ library](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview).

Comment: I agree that this definitely works (and would be my preferred method in a vacuum), but just want to point out that, depending on the size of the source, this may be computationally intensive compared to the annoying to use .Distinct(IEqualityComparer) option.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Its works like a charm :).Can you gave me an example for the same using Distinct .It would be more helpful for us for understanding